# Viewing test points (instance of a test case) associated with a tester in TFS (MS Test Professional)

Tags: testcase, tfs

If a test case is assigned to the person who maintains the test and a tester gets associated with a test point, which is a specific configuration of a test, then how does the tester know which tests they should be running?

As you can't query a tester field or have an assigned to me equivalent for tester.

It seems like a big oversight in this tool or I'm just using it in the wrong way. I know that you can filter in Test Manager to a specific tester.

I'm struggling to understand how you can manager a team of testers, if they can't see what tests they need to run.

For reference, I have already read: [Can I query on the tester field in TFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29614300/can-i-query-on-the-tester-field-in-tfs)

Comment: Use the "Test case manager" view and add the column "Tester" to it.

Comment: Thanks. Is it no possible to do the same through the TFS web interface?

Comment: It can be done through the TFS web interface - but your testers will all need to add the columns Tester and Configuration to their view of the web interface (if the columns aren't already there). They can do this via the Column Options link that shows on every TFS web interface query view.

Comment: I see, so in the Test area within TFS, they could order by Tester. I guess i'd need to make a query based test suit, which includes the test cases associated with child test suites of a test plan, so testers could easily see what tests are associate with them without going into every test suite... If that's even possible.

It seems convoluted. I would be interested to know how other people manage a team of testers with this tool, as I must be going about it the wrong way.